# Bootstrap dropdown Menu not displaying for the static menu

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a static menu on my webpage. The dropdown menu in the same is not displaying. I have the following code for the menu.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse" id="navbar-icons">
            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">someting2</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

I am unable to see the **dropdown menu**.I have the menu working fine but the dropdown menu is not visible. But it exists on the DOM.I can see the menu using view source in Chrome.I am able to see the dropdown menus for a resolution smaller than 700px that is when the main menu collapses but not other wise.

Please help me make the menu visible.

Comment: Do you mean to say that, you don't get the `dropdown` option in the menubar?

Comment: Hi Greenhorn, I get the dropdown option but do not see the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **collapse** class from the `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse" id="navbar-icons">`. because collapse class hides the dropdown.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyuf8env/)

Comment: Hi Harshal, I have removed the collapse class but it still doesn't display the dropdown menu

Comment: You should have jquery having version 1.9 or above. Prefer latest version of JQuery.

Comment: I do have the latest jquery. I am unable to see the dropdown .So I tried popover but that is also hiding. Its showing the existence in DOM but not displaying. When I resize the browser I am able to see the dropdown menus but for a resolution of a laptop its not displaying.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle that I have added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given the all the required CDNs and CSS in the right order(in the head) as below:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right" id="navbar-icons">
    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">someting2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">dropdown1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dropdown2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dropdown3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: The second part of the code falls within `<body>`. Notice that I gave `class="collapse"` outside navbar's `<ul>` tag in a separate `<div>`. If you don't need "collapse", you may just remove the associated **div** tags.

Comment: Hi greenhorn, I have the required CSS and js files in place. The problem is I am unable to view the dropdown menu. The main menu is working fine but the dropdown menu is not displaying,

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **collapse** from your code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar-icons">
    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">someting2</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">dropdown1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dropdown2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dropdown3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Static Top Navbar</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="./">Static top</a></li>
<li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

tryout this one:

`JS Fiddle Link:` http://jsfiddle.net/abidkhanweb/ZS4L7/1066/

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I had included a `overflow:hidden` style for the the `<li>` tag of the menu. This caused the drop down menu to be hidden since the drop down is considered as an extension of the same DOM element. I apologize for the mistake and thank you all for your quick response.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `collapse` class from `ul`.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar-icons">
...
```